# Rendering field_view_field with extra fields

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a field which is being called with `field_view_field()`, and I want to add some extra parts.

```
$badges = field_view_field('profile2', $profile, 'field_badge', 'user_header');
if ($badges) {
  foreach ($badges as $b) {
    $b['title'] = $b['#term']->name;
    $b['link'] = l(t('external link'), '1234');
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the term name as the title since it describes the image being rendered, and the link goes to a node. The logs are suggesting that I am trying to iterate across a Profile so that call fails, but I am wondering if I have missed the Drupal way of adding the title and the links to the rendering array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by overriding [template_taxonomy_theme_preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/template_preprocess_taxonomy_term/7) and then using the theme('image', $variables) function to output the styled images correctly with the link.